# How can I use just the relative path in a param value?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, relative-path, param

```
<param name="source" value= "/ClientBin/Gantt_SL1.xap"/>
```

This involves HTML markup and Silverlight. Basically in the markup I have the line above. What I would like to do is use this relative path throughout my markup. I have different web pages in other sub folders that also reference this SL xap. When I want to use it however, I have to do something like this:

```
<param name="source" value= "../ClientBin/Gantt_SL1.xap"/>
```

I rather not have to be worrying about how many "../" I have to put in front of a path to make sure it gets resolved. Is there a .NET, Javascript, or JQuery method that allows me to use the relative path in the root, sub-folder, sub-folder of a sub-folder without doing the whole "../" business? Something like:

```
//from some library
<param name="source" value= ResolveFullPath("/ClientBin/Gantt_SL1.xap")/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ResolveUrl:

```
<param name="source" value='<%= ResolveUrl("~/ClientBin/Gantt_SL1.xap")%>' />
```